# Dirt Rally Start Failing

Tags: steam, endeavouros

I'm having problems starting Dirt Rally on Steam with EndeavourOS.

Currently I'm having these errors on the console:

```
/mnt/24900711-3d8d-4042-bbe3-7762ddf28edb/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/DiRT Rally/bin/DirtRally: /usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /mnt/24900711-3d8d-4042-bbe3-7762ddf28edb/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/DiRT Rally/bin/../lib/x86_64/libcurl.so.4)
/mnt/24900711-3d8d-4042-bbe3-7762ddf28edb/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/DiRT Rally/bin/DirtRally: /usr/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /mnt/24900711-3d8d-4042-bbe3-7762ddf28edb/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/DiRT Rally/bin/../lib/x86_64/libcurl.so.4)
```

What does it mean?

Comment: upvote for being interested in the meaning of the error message

Comment: I found a partial solution, if put this files https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=liblber-2.4.so.2 to usr/lib, the error disapears, but then, I can't use sudo, says wrong ELF class. Seems a kind of problem with 32-64bit libraries as usual.

Comment: Try starting steam with `STEAM_RUNTIME_PREFER_HOST_LIBRARIES=0 steam` as described here: [https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/531286-DiRT-Rally-wont-start-anymore-due-to-OpenSSL-1-1](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/531286-DiRT-Rally-wont-start-anymore-due-to-OpenSSL-1-1). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252196/curl-usr-local-lib-libldap-r-2-4-so-2-no-version-information-available

Comment: yes, launching with this the error is not showed, but appears a lot of "Fontconfig warning:", and I miss a little message on my question, this is "[0922/124111:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(212)] Running without renderer sandbox
" appears too. Launching steam with this parameter is the only way to solve the issue?

Comment: I think you have to provide the correct library versions or set/modify the  LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to the correct library path (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)). Do you have those libraries in the `…/steamapps/common/DiRT Rally/lib/x86_64` directory?

Comment: Not exactly. The near library is "libcurl.so.4", this is in the dirt rally/lib/x86_64 directory, that is in the error message. The dir have libcef.so, libpdf.so, libSDL2-2.0.5.so, libSDL2_image-2.0.1.so and libsteam_api.so.

Comment: [Another guy](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/6tik79/dirt_rally_on_tumbleweed/) solved it by deleting `libcurl.so.4` in the games directory and linking 
the local version to this directory, but that's rather hacky. Does starting with `STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam` make a difference (see [here](https://en.opensuse.org/Steam#Loading_Steam_without_local_runtime_to_avoid_crash_or_game_play_without_sound))?

Comment: I don't understand what do you say with " make a difference", but I don't like to launch anything with "special" commands, the other games that I have are running without problems. I like the solution "linking libcurl.so.4 from games to local", this solves the issue and is great. Problem solved. A lot of thanks!

Comment: @Jordi4321 As this solves your problem, please write this up as an answer. You can [accept your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) later.

Comment: Only a last doubt. Is a little bit stupid but, the system libcurl.so.4 file is a symlink to libcurl.so.4.6.0, then, when the system is updated, is updated this symlink to a newer version of "libcurl.so.x.x.x? If this is, the solution is perfect. Initially I made a symlink to libcurl.so.4.6.0 on steam folder, but is a mistake.

Comment: @Jordi4321 Yes, for example the [libcurl3_7.52.1-5+deb9u9_amd64.deb](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3_7.52.1-5+deb9u9_amd64.deb) (Debian Stretch) 
package creates two symlinks `libcurl.so.3 -> libcurl.so.4` and `libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.4.0`. So it should work if you symlink `libcurl.so.4`.

Comment: Perfect a lot of thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution for this issue is simply make a symlink to libcurl.so.4 from DiRT Rally/lib/x86_64. The command exactly is this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 [...]/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/DiRT Rally/lib/x86_64/libcurl.so.4
```

Comment: Well, this solves the error and for a little bit of time the game started perfectly, but, then, again I have the error code 6 when I launch the game. I sent an email to feral. I don't understand what is happening. When it has started I disabled the launcher, and is working again. The error that appears before the crash, possibly is this: Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561197985965684 [API loaded no]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
  what():  basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file

Comment: Now, I found that when the game fails to start, if I close the session and restart it (with same user), the game starts with any problem. Possibly a service or anything causes the issue?